# Problems with graphical display of topic prevalence over time covariates when using structural topic model

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBshv.png)
The graph above is the relationship between the time and the topic 13, I would like to know what the dashed line in the plot means. And whether there is something wrong with the plot I generated? I see some plots.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxVd.png)
As shown above, the dashed line is closer to the solid line and the trend is similar. Is there something wrong with the plots I made?

Here is my code

```
library(stm)
library(igraph)
## INGEST: Reading and processing text data
library(readxl)
data <- read_excel(path="D:/word_zh5.xlsx", sheet="Sheet1", col_names= TRUE)
processed <- textProcessor(data$documents, metadata = data,wordLengths = c(1,Inf)) 
out <- prepDocuments(processed$documents, processed$vocab, processed$meta)
docs <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
## PREPARE: Associating text with metadata
plotRemoved(processed$documents, lower.thresh = seq(1, 600, by = 5))
out <- prepDocuments(processed$documents, processed$vocab, processed$meta, lower.thresh = 30)
shortdoc <- substr(out$meta$documents,1,200)
poliblogPrevFit <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K = 13, prevalence = ~rating     +s(day), max.em.its = 75, data = out$meta, init.type = "Spectral")
prep <- estimateEffect(1:13 ~ rating + s(day), poliblogPrevFit, meta = out$meta, uncertainty = "Global")
pdf("time.pdf")
plot(prep, "day", method = "continuous", topics = 13,main="topic13",model = poliblogPrevFit, printlegend   = FALSE, xlab = "Time")
dev.off()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO water. The x-axis in your first plot starts prior to 2005, but 2019 in your second plot. This _might_ explain your issue. Try only plotting your data from 2019-01-01 to see if that returns your expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much, you gave me the first comment. But figure 2 is showing the results from others and is not linked to my x-axis. I am now starting to think that maybe there is nothing big wrong with the plot I generated? Because looking all over the stm I don't know how it could be going. Anyway, thank you very much.